# Hbase/Phoenix Salted Tables: Hbase does not add salt byte when putting new data

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

What we have here is a salted table created using Apache Phoenix.

When upserting a new row through Phoenix, it adds a transparent salt byte to the rowkey *(eg: \x0E)*, the salt byte is visible from Hbase shell but not from phoenix.

**Problem:**

When we add a new row through Hbase shell, the rowkey isn't salted (no salt byte at the beginning) and the row can't be selected from phoenix using `where rowkey = 'my_rowkey'`, although it appears when `where rowkey like '%my_rowkey'`.

> Note: another use case affected by this problem is when trying to update a row through phoenix it ends up adding a new row instead of updating.

Comment: what was your create table statement?